# How do you specify the project configuration when publishing to an Azure website from source control?

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment, azure-web-app-service

I have configured my Azure website to [deploy from a Bitbucket Mercurial repository](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/#Step75). I only have one branch. From the logs (see below), it looks like the deployment process uses the *Release* configuration.

> ...
>   MyProject.Web ->
>   D:\home\site\repository\MyProject.Web\bin\MyProject.Web.dll
>
> Transformed Web.config using
>   D:\home\site\repository\MyProject.Web\Web.Release.config 
>         into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
>   ...

Let's say I have three environments, DEV, BETA, and PROD. I have web.config transformations for each since they may have different connection strings or various other different settings across each environment. **How can I specify a different configuration?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `.deployment` file in the root of your repo and put this in it

```
[config]
SCM_BUILD_ARGS=-p:Configuration=Debug
```

Alternatively you can specify that in the site's App Settings from portal. like this:

```
SCM_BUILD_ARGS=-p:Configuration=Debug
```

For more about custom deployment settings you can [refer to this](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings)